# Render ExpressJS into div identified by id

Tags: javascript, express, pug

I am new to the **ExpressJS** and **Jade** game, as like today new. I can't figure out how to render data into a `div` identified by its `id` attribute. Here is my sample Jade file:

```
extends layout

block content
  div
    h1= title
    div(id="content", class="main")
```

I want to pass the data into the `div` with `id` `Content`. Here is the snippet of my ExpressJS file:

```
...
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('index', { title: 'Hello World!' });
    res.render('index', { content: 'Wazzzaaapp' });
  });
...
```

I'm able to display the title *Hello world* but not the *Wazzzaaapp*.

Sample screenshot of what I got:

[image: ejs sample screenshot]

Is this possible to do in `render` or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the correct or actual answer, but I got it solved by adding (in the Jade/ Pug file of course) either the placeholder `#{var_name}` or `= var_name` as:

```
div(id="content", class="main")= content
```

OR

```
div(id="content", class="main") #{content}
```

either one works and shows the *Wazzzaaapp* output as intended:

[image: ejs screenshot sample]

Hope this solution helps others!